# MySQL check if field has number in it

Tags: mysql, select, comparison

I'm looking to do a simple comparison test in MySQL, I have a field that stores ID's like so:

```
1;2;23;12
```

Or if only one option was selected when creating that entry it would only be one:

```
2
```

At any rate I am looking to filter my select query to find entries in the DB that have for instance the ID 2 in them. So I need some sort of comparison to compare that id 2 against that column with those values and a possible single value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [find_in_set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function:

```
Select 
   *
from 
   your_table
where 
   FIND_IN_SET('2',REPLACE( '1;2;23;12', ';' , ',' ) ) > 0
```

I would recommend to you to normalize database (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form)
Also, notice to you that this kind of queries don't has high performance.

Comment: Awesome! Yeah I'm not really worried about speed with this, since there really aren't going to be many in there record wise, it saves me from having to do a new form for adding and a second table for xreference.